# $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\sim\ln n$

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I would like to know how the author got  $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}}{\ln(n)} \longrightarrow 1$  from $ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} =\ln(n)+\lambda+o(1)$

[image]

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}}{ln(n)}=1+\frac{\lambda}{ \ln(n)} +o(\frac{1}{\ln(n)})$$

when n goes to infinity we got that

$$ \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}}{ln(n)}=1+o(0)$$

Comment: Divide by $\ln(n)$ and take limits on each side.

Comment: An $o(1)$ term is a term that goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @educ Tablet computers are very poor for any serious tasks.

Comment: yes its not for serious tasks

Comment: @Educ I am sorry that you don't take participating in m.se seriously. $\frown$

Comment: my laptop is broken now

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown assuming the worst of students isn't the best community practice either. Especially as it seems his normal methods are simply not currently available and he was merely agreeing with your sentiment in earnest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that relies on elementary analysis only.

---

Let $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k -\log(n)$.  Recalling that $\log(x)\ge \frac{x-1}{x}$ for all $x>0$, we have

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac1{n+1}-\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\le 0\tag 1$$

Therefore, $(1)$ establishes that the sequence $a_n$ is decreasing.

We also see that

$$a_n\ge 1+\int_2^n \frac1x\,dx-\log(n)=1-\log(2)\tag2$$

Therefore, $(2)$ establishes that $a_n$ is bounded below.

Since $a_n$ is decreasing and bounded below, it converges.

Now we denote by $\gamma$, the limit

$$\gamma=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k -\log(n)\right)\tag 3$$

Then, using $(3)$ we can write

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k =\log(n)+\gamma+o(1) \tag 4$$

where $o(1)$ is the "little o" notation.

From $(4)$ it is easy to see that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k}{\log(n)}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac\gamma{\log(n)+}+\frac{o(1)}{\log(n)}\right)=1$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: could you elaborate the last step

Comment: Sure.  $\log(n)/\log(n)=1$ and $\gamma/\log(n)\to 0$ and $o(1)\to 0$

Answer (score 3):

Use the standard inequalities

> $$\log n-\log 2 = \int_2^n {dt\over t}\le \sum_{j=2}^n{1\over k}\le \int_1^n{dt\over t} = \log n$$

Now divide everything by $\log n$ and take limits. The squeeze theorem gives the result.

Answer (score 1):

You have $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\ln n+\gamma+o(1)$. So
$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k}{\ln n}-1=\frac{\gamma+o(1)}{\ln n}.$$
In this fraction the numerator is bounded and the denominator tends to infinity, so the whole thing tends to zero.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{H_n}{\log n} = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}}{\log(n+1)-\log n} = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot\frac{1}{n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}=\color{red}{1} $$
simply follows from the [Stoltz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).
As an alternative approach you may notice that $\frac{1}{n}=\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ and that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\log(N+1) $$
because the LHS is a telescopic sum.